# How to log into pokemon go using google WITHOUT adding the google account to the android phone?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

I usually play on my personal (ios) phone. But I forgot to bring it with me to work. I want to play on my work phone, but I don't want to add my personal google account to the work phone. Is there a way to log into pokemon go WITHOUT having to add the google account to the phone?

Comment: If there doesn't appear to be any obvious way to do this, probably not.  It's likely that the games code is integrated to work with the Google Accounts on the phone already only.

Comment: If you're trying to sign in to the profile you already created with your Google account, there's no other way to do this.  If you just want to play the game, you can make a [Pokémon Trainer Club](https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/sign-up/) account, but it won't have any of your old data.

Answer (score 1):

On android devices, everything is linked directly to the saved accounts on the device, and therefore there is no way to log into a google account for Pokemon through a browser like Chrome.

The only other option would be through a Pokemon Trainer Club account as mentioned by Chase Sandmann if you are trying to avoid logging in.